# Mapstruct 1.3.1.Final with springboot 2.6.3 - circular reference

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I upgraded springboot version from 2.2.6.RELEASE up to 2.6.3

I have next mappers:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {NoteMapper.class})
public abstract class BasicMapper {
    ...
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {BasicMapper.class})
public abstract class NoteMapper {
    ...
}
```

mapstruct dependecies:

```
annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.1.Final"
annotationProcessor "org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.1.Final"
```

mapstruct generates next classes:

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "...",
    comments = "version: 1.3.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 11.0.11 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class BasicMapperImpl extends BasicMapper {

    @Autowired
    private NoteMapper noteMapper;
    ....
}

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "...",
    comments = "version: 1.3.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 11.0.11 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class NoteMapperImpl extends NoteMapper {

    @Autowired
    private BasicMapper basicMapper;
    ...
}
```

After upgrading version of springboot I caught next error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'basicMapperImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'noteMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'noteMapperImpl': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Is there any solution to avoid this circular reference?

Comment: By not using circular references. They both use each other so which needs to be created first? You can disable the behaviour (as documented in the release notes, which I assume you read!) and get it as before, however circular dependencies are generally a code smell and should be avoided. .

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to avoid a circular refence, while still keeping 2 seperate interfaces.

```
// No @Mapper annotation, that is handled by the BasicAndNoteMapper.
public interface BasicMapper {
  // BasicMapper mapping method
}

// No @Mapper annotation, that is handled by the BasicAndNoteMapper.
public interface NoteMapper {
  // NoteMapper mapping method
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
abstract class BasicAndNoteMapper implements BasicMapper, NoteMapper {
    // no methods needed, you can place the MapStruct annotations on the methods of the interface mappers.
}
```

This will result in 1 mapper implementation, but 2 separate interfaces. Important is that the interfaces do not have an `@Mapper` annotation, while the abstract class here does. The circular reference will now take place between methods instead of classes, which is not a problem.

Comment: it worked great. the only thing I had to change the names of the methods.